# Open Excel from server in client's browser using VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript

Requirement: To open an Excel file at client side, which is stored in the Server.

I am trying to open an Excel file using VBScript. The actual file resides on the server, but the user must have the access to make a copy of that file in his local machine.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks,
Muthu

Comment: Have you tried *downloading* the file, and asking the user to select "Open"?

Comment: @Cody Gray: I guess, we need to tell how to download the file to the local PC.

Comment: You certainly don't need VBScript. Just place a link on your web page to the Excel document on the server. Whenever the user clicks it, their browser will take care of the rest. Not sure what else there is I can explain.

Comment: @Kanini: Ah, I just realized you're not the original poster. Sorry about that. But I'm still not sure what more there is to explain about how to download a file.

Comment: is the VBScript server or client side?

Answer (score 2):

Create a link to the file

```
<a href="exceldoc.xls">Download here</a>
```

Place the above code in your html page. Then when the user clicks this link they will be able to save or open the file.